# How can I find out whether a server supports the Range header?

Tags: http, http-headers

I have been trying to stream audio from a particular point by using the Range header values but I always get the song right from the beginning. I am doing this through a program so am not sure whether the problem lies in my code or on the server.

How can I find out whether the server supports the Range header param?

Thanks.

Comment: See this question on Server Fault: [Test a server for byte range support?](http://serverfault.com/q/547073/104579)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The way the [HTTP spec](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.35.2) defines it, if the server knows how to support the `Range` header, it will. That in turn, requires it to return a [206 Partial Content](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.2.7) response code with a [`Content-Range`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.16) header, when it returns content to you. Otherwise, it will simply ignore the `Range` header in your request, and return a 200 response code.

This might seem silly, but are you sure you're crafting a valid HTTP request header? All too commonly, I forget to specify HTTP/1.1 in the request, or forget to specify the Range specifier, such as "bytes".

Oh, and if all you want to do is *check*, then just send a HEAD request instead of a GET request. Same headers, same everything, just "HEAD" instead of "GET". If you receive a `206` response, you'll know `Range` is supported, and otherwise you'll get a `200` response.

Comment: Using Python request, the head does not return 206 on the server which I know supports range, but the response headers contains `Accept-Ranges`.

Comment: @hpaknia I think that it depends on the server side implementation.

Answer (score 21):

This is for others searching how to do this. You can use curl:

```
curl -I http://exampleserver.com/example_video.mp4
```

In the header you should see

```
Accept-Ranges: bytes
```

You can go further and test retrieving a range

```
curl --header "Range: bytes=100-107" -I http://exampleserver.com/example_vide0.mp4
```

and in the headers you should see

```
HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content
```

and

```
Content-Range: bytes 100-107/10000000
Content-Length: 8
```

[instead of 10000000 you'll see the length of the file]

Comment: Server may accept range request even if it does not sent the Accept-Ranges header, see https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.5 As for the further testing, see https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.2.7

Answer (score 7):

Although I am a bit late in answering this question, I think my answer will help future visitors. Here is a python method that detects whether a server supports range queries or not.

```
def accepts_byte_ranges(self, effective_url):
    """Test if the server supports multi-part file download. Method expects effective (absolute) url."""
    import pycurl
    import cStringIO
    import re

    c = pycurl.Curl()
    header = cStringIO.StringIO()

    # Get http header
    c.setopt(c.URL, effective_url)
    c.setopt(c.NOBODY, 1)
    c.setopt(c.HEADERFUNCTION, header.write)
    c.perform()
    c.close()

    header_text = header.getvalue()
    header.close()

    verbose_print(header_text)

    # Check if server accepts byte-ranges
    match = re.search('Accept-Ranges:\s+bytes', header_text)
    if match:
        return True
    else:
        # If server explicitly specifies "Accept-Ranges: none" in the header, we do not attempt partial download.
        match = re.search('Accept-Ranges:\s+none', header_text)
        if match:
            return False
        else:
            c = pycurl.Curl()

            # There is still hope, try a simple byte range query
            c.setopt(c.RANGE, '0-0') # First byte
            c.setopt(c.URL, effective_url)
            c.setopt(c.NOBODY, 1)
            c.perform()

            http_code = c.getinfo(c.HTTP_CODE)
            c.close()

            if http_code == 206: # Http status code 206 means byte-ranges are accepted
                return True
            else:
                return False
```

Answer (score 5):

One way is just to try, and check the response. In your case, it appears the server doesn't support ranges.

Alternatively, do a GET or HEAD on the URI, and check for the [Accept-Ranges response header](http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc2616.html#rfc.section.14.5).

Answer (score 0):

- You can use `GET` method with `0-0` `Range` request header, and check whether the response code is 206 or not, which will respond with 
  the first and last bytes of the response body
- You also can use `HEAD` method do the same thing as the first session which will get the same response header and code without response body

> Furthermore, you can check `Accept-Ranges` on the response header to judge whether it can support range, but please notice if the value is `none` on `Accept-Ranges` field, it means it can't support range, and if the response header doesn't have `Accept-Ranges` field you also can't finger out it can't support range from it.

There is another thing you have to know if you are using `0-` `Range` on the request header with `GET` method to check the response code, the response body message will be cached automatically on the TCP receive window until the cache is full.