# Only retrieve specific parts of a webpage for lower network usage?

Tags: python, http, web-scraping

This may seem like a stupid question, but is it possible to retrieve only part of a webpage (as in, have the server send only a particular `<div>`)? I know it's possible to only [get the HEAD of a page via HTTP (at least in Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/843401/4900327).

I think it's in direct violation of the way HTTP GET works but I decided to ask anyway.

I'm thinking about webscraping thousands of pages, and I noticed the data usage gets pretty high. I don't need all of the page, just the relevant part.

Answer (score 2):

It depends what you mean by "specific part of the page".

The HTTP protocol does allow to ask for part of content using starting position and response size, see `Range` header as described in [other SO question Retreive part of web page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1538952/retrieve-partial-web-page).

If you want to get something like "just the table on the page", you are out of luck, as there is no way to express this kind of request in HTTP.