# how can i test whether my server supports range requests?

Tags: http-headers, jplayer, range

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I find out whether a server supports the Range header?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/720419/how-can-i-find-out-whether-a-server-supports-the-range-header)

I want to make a jPlayer media player but it says that the server must enable Range requests.

It says that this is easy to check for by seeing if your server's resonse includes the Accept-Ranges in its header - but I don't know how to do this 'easy' thing.

I think it is the same question as [How can I find out whether a server supports the Range header?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/720419/how-can-i-find-out-whether-a-server-supports-the-range-header?answertab=active#tab-top) but I need a step by step idiot guide to how to carry out the test.  I couldn't work it out from that answer.  Can anyone help?  I guess I need to upload a php page to my server with some code on it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

OK well apparently this is how you can do it (thanks to Mark Panaghiston at JPlayer for this)..

- Navigate to the url address of a video (mp4 in my case) on the server in question in Chrome/Firefox.
- Open up the developer tools (in Chrome, shortcut <kbd>CTRL-SHIFT-i</kbd> or <kbd>F12</kbd>)
- Switch to the `network` tab of the developer tools
- Select the video/file in question
- Then click for the `Headers` tab for information
- Look to see if you have a Header Response for `Accept Ranges: Bytes`

If this `Accept Ranges` has a value like bytes, then it means range requests are accepted.

[image: Showing the developer tools F12 menu for Network and headers]